# DLL load failure while installing module

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Whenever I am trying to install any module I get the following error

```
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Agniva Roy\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 9, in <module>
    import logging.handlers
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 26, in <module>
    import logging, socket, os, pickle, struct, time, re
  File "c:\users\agniva roy\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please do help me out

Comment: did you tried to upgrade your `pip` with `pip install --upgrade pip` command?

Comment: Yes, I did it a few days earlier but now this command also doesn't work I am stuck!